Young's inequality for weak $L^{\infty}$
Young's convolution can be generalized for the case of $L^{p,\infty}$ functions:
$$
\|f\ast g\|_{L^r} \le C_{p,q,r} \|f\|_{L^{p,\infty}} \|g\|_{L^q},
$$
for any $p,q,r \in (1,\infty)$ such that $1/p + 1/q = 1/r + 1$.
I'm interested in the case $p=\infty$:
$$
\|f\ast g\|_{L^r} \le C_{q,r} \|f\|_{L^{\infty,\infty}} \|g\|_{L^q}?
$$
A definition of $L^{\infty,\infty}$ can be found on page two of the following paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.1207.
It was already pointed out in 1 that in the case $p=1$ the statement is false. I think the statement I just gave is not true but I have no counterexample. It would also be interesting if it is possible to give a explicit formula for the constant $C_{p,q,r}$. I would be grateful for any hints!
